Calculate the average of multiple columns within a collection - powerapps
I have a collection within a powerapps canvas, where I am trying to calculate the average of any entries within multiple columns.

Specifically, I want to find the average of the values within the 2nd to 8th column of the above collection.
The collection name is "Coll_Records"
The column names that I want to find the average of are "Dip1" through to "Dip7"
I can find the average of a single column no problem, but obviously wouldn't be correct if I were to find the average of the averages of each column.
I have tried using an array within the average formula with no success
average(Coll_Records,{Dip1,Dip2,Dip3,Dip4,Dip5,Dip6,Dip7})
I have also tried calculating the average "from scratch" but having issue with the count element.
I'm able to find the sum of all the values fine, but cant calculate the total count with a view of summing the total count per column.
I've tried
Count(Coll_Record,Dip1)
Count(Dip1)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Try CountA as an alternative Count, CountA, CountIf, and CountRows functions

One solution is to do use Sum() for each of the rows and count columns with values using a Sum() in conjunction with an If(). E.g.

First Avg-7/5/4 is a sum of all the values for that row divided by the number of columns that contain values
Formula for that:
Sum(ThisItem.Dip1,ThisItem.Dip2,ThisItem.Dip3,ThisItem.Dip4,ThisItem.Dip5,ThisItem.Dip6,ThisItem.Dip7)/
Sum(
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip1),1,0),
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip2),1,0),
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip3),1,0),
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip4),1,0),
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip5),1,0),
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip6),1,0),
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.Dip7),1,0))

Avg-7 is same as above but always dividing by 7
Sum(ThisItem.Dip1,ThisItem.Dip2,ThisItem.Dip3,ThisItem.Dip4,ThisItem.Dip5,ThisItem.Dip6,ThisItem.Dip7)/7

